# Testing Router.push() with jest and sinon

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, sinon

Trying to test this function within a class 'Nav' my aim it to test Router, or more importantly gain coverage on Router.push(/)

```
<AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static">
            <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                {authenticated && this.state.layoutMode ==='desktop' ? (
                    <Grid container
                        direction ="row"
                        justify="flex-end"
                        alignItems="center">
                        <div className={classes.root}>
                            <Tabs id="Tab" className = {classes.tabBar} value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                <Tab label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                                <Tab label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                                <Tab label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                                <Tab label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                                <Tab label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                                <Tab label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                            </Tabs>
                        </div>
                    </Grid>
                ) : (
                    authenticated && <BurgerMenu/>
                )}
```

My test looks like this so far

```
describe('Test for navigation', () => {
let sandbox;

beforeAll(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
});

afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
});

it('should render with data', () => {
    const stub = jest.fn();
    sandbox.stub(Router, 'push').callsFake(stub);
    const wrapper = shallow(<Nav authenticated />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(stub.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
    wrapper.find(AppBar).props().onClick('test');
    expect(stub.mock.calls.length).toBe(7);
});
```

});

However i am running into a problem, i cant seem to find the prop of 'AppBar' I have imported Nav into the test but the error reads, "Method "props" is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead"
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is you are trying to call `onClick` prop on `AppBar`, but that is a prop of each `Tab`. Having in mind you are trying to reach more coverage, you should test it like this:

Let's supose your code is in render function and a `id` prop is valid for each `Tab`:

```
render(){
<AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static">
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
            {authenticated && this.state.layoutMode ==='desktop' ? (
                <Grid container
                    direction ="row"
                    justify="flex-end"
                    alignItems="center">
                    <div className={classes.root}>
                        <Tabs id="Tab" className = {classes.tabBar} value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            <Tab id="Tab1" label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                            <Tab id="Tab2" label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                            <Tab id="Tab3" label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                            <Tab id="Tab4" label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                            <Tab id="Tab5" label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                            <Tab id="Tab6" label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                        </Tabs>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
            ) : (
                authenticated && <BurgerMenu/>
            )}

        </Toolbar>
</AppBar> }
```

Now let´s find the `Tab1` in your test:

```
it('should render with data', () => {
    const stub = jest.fn();
    sandbox.stub(Router, 'push').callsFake(stub);
    const wrapper = shallow(<Nav authenticated />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(stub.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
    const tab1 = wrapper.find(`[id="Tab6"]`);   
    tab1.simulate("clic");

    expect(stub.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);   
});
```